# How do I make an ASP.NET MVC application use my Membership tables?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6

I let Visual Studio generate the sample project, which I intend to change to my needs. Then I let VS generate a Model based on my database, which added a new connectionString to the Web.config. My database has the ASP.NET Membership tables in it already, but the sample app still insists on using the tables in a database it generated. How do I make it use my tables?

My connectionStrings are the following:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-TAD-20141109115206.mdf;Initial Catalog=aspnet-TAD-20141109115206;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="TADEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.TADModel.csdl|res://*/Models.TADModel.ssdl|res://*/Models.TADModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=(localdb)\v11.0;initial catalog=TAD;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

The first one is used by the sample app, the second is my database. Apart from these connectionStrings I can't seem to find any mention of connections, so I've been unsuccessful in making it use my tables.

Comment: 1st connection string is usung `aspnet-TAD-20141109115206` the 2nd `TAD`, what happens if you change the 1st to use TAD as well?

Comment: @artm It crashes horribly: `Cannot attach file '[too long]\TAD\App_Data\aspnet-TAD-20141109115206.mdf' as database 'TAD' because this database name is already attached with file 'C:\Users\simon\TAD.mdf'`

Comment: Search your solution for `DefaultConnection`, see where it comes up, replace it with `TADEntities`

Comment: @artm This is starting to go somewhere. But I'm getting lots of error messages, presumably because table names don't match.

Comment: Could be. Compare schemas between the two databases, see what the differences are but I'm not sure if it'll be as simple as renaming tables. If they were using the same membership then the schemas would probably match, if they don't match, two databases might be using different memberships.

Comment: @artm Most likely. It might be better to just delete everything from the sample project and start anew.

Comment: Yeah, that seems logical. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Does yours membership table have a unique field in both tables? If you have username in the membership table, you could query it by the authenticated user after login.

Comment: It is using two separate databases at the moment. Both have the Membership tables. But my database has the tables I designed. So I want the app to use the Membership tables in my database.

Comment: Can you move the table to the sample DB ?

Comment: Possibly, but it seems like the Membership classes used in the sample DB are somewhat more limited compared to the full Membership model. No idea *if* it will affect me, but I guess I better play it safe.